# Why can't I see the Ubuntu Task bar on my Jetson Nano 2GB developer kit?

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

I just got a Jetson Nano 2gb developer kit and installed Jetpack 4.6 on it, and when I power it on, this is the desktop I see.

[image]

There isn't the taskbar that shows up generally which looks like this:

[image]

P.S: Sorry if my doubt sounds stupid, I am new to Linux and Ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe ask in https://superuser.com/ instead

Comment: @U.Windl Hey, I will surely, but I don't think the answer will be guaranteed there, but I will try :D